# NgRx effect method not subscribed using component store

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-component-store

```
export interface RiskWorkFlowState {
    workFlows: WorkflowStageDto[],
    totalCount: number
}

export const initialState: RiskWorkFlowState = {
    workFlows: [],
    totalCount: 0
}

@Injectable()
export class RiskWorkFlowStore extends ComponentStore<RiskWorkFlowState>{

    constructor(private riskWorkflowServiceProxy: RiskWorkflowServiceProxy) {
        super(initialState);
    }

    //#region selectors
    readonly workFlows$: Observable<WorkflowStageDto[]> = this.select(state => state.workFlows);
    //#endregion

    readonly setAsError = this.updater((state, message: string) => ({
        ...state,
        callState: toError(message),
    }));

    readonly getAllStages = this.effect((trigger$) => {
        return trigger$.pipe(
            switchMap(() => {
                return combineLatest([this.defaultPageSize$, this.skipCount$, this.workFlows$])
                    .pipe(map(([defaultPageSize, skipCount, storeWorkFlow]) => {
                        return this.riskWorkflowServiceProxy.getAll('', '', defaultPageSize, skipCount).pipe(
                            tapResponse(
                                (workFlow) => {
                                    // Some working logic
                                },
                                (error: ApiException) => this.setAsError(error.message),
                            )
                        )
                    }))
            })
        )
    });
}
```

In the component I have below provider, because using it as component store

```
providers: [RiskWorkFlowStore]
allStages$ : Observable<WorkflowStageDto[]>;
constructor(
        private _riskWorkFlowStore : RiskWorkFlowStore
    ) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
     this._riskWorkFlowStore.getAllStages();
     this.allStages$ = this._riskWorkFlowStore.workFlows$;
 }
```

And in the HTML  `<ng-container *ngFor="let stage of allStages$ | async;"> </ng-container>`

The Http method is not been called, if I subscribe manually it works, however not with the above code

Comment: Are you sure the `ng-container` is not located in a `*ngIf` which would prevent the container to be reached ?

Comment: Yes there are no NgIf

Comment: Not sure why it is working with withLatestFrom but not with combineLatest